# Can An iOS App Receive Google Drive Push Notifications Directly?

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

The question pretty much says it. By "Directly" I mean without having to create anything (such as a web server) other than the app itself. As best as I can determine the answer is no. I'd be thrilled to learn otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/push), you need to set up your receiving URL, or "Webhook" callback receiver.

> This is an HTTPS server that handles the API notification messages that are triggered when a resource changes.

You also need to:

> - Register the domain of your receiving URL. For example, if you plan to use https://sampledomain.com/notifications as your receiving URL, you need to register https://sampledomain.com.
> - Set up a notification channel for each resource endpoint you want to watch. A channel specifies routing information for notification messages. As part of the channel setup, you identify the specific URL where you want to receive notifications. Whenever a channel's resource changes, the Drive API sends a notification message as a POST request to that URL.

Comment: Thank you for the information [ which I have already seen :-) ]. So, would you then say that the answer to my question is No?